# How can I make a top 5 Scoreboard on python?

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a top 5 scoreboard from a csv file but I am struggling.

This is my code, It would be appreciated if anyone can help

```
while True:
if attempt == 2:
    print("You have no more guesses...You Loose!")
    print("Here is the scoreboard")

    user = str(input("Enter a name to save your highscore: "))
    file = open ("scoreboard.csv", "a")
    file.write("\n")
    file.write(user)
    file.write(",")
    file.write(str(points))
    file.write("pts")
    file.write("\n")
```

Comment: What specific problem are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this.
You don't need a new line at the start an end unless you want a line break between them.
You also want to use a "with open" to close the file automatically.

```
while True:
if attempt == 2:
    print("You have no more guesses...You Loose!")
    print("Here is the scoreboard")
    user = str(input("Enter a name to save your highscore: "))
    with open("scoreboard.csv", "a") as output:
        output.write("\n"+user+","+str(points)+" pts")
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV module is very convenient.
`user` and `points` are followed your inputs.
It is used Python 3.6+.

```py
import csv


with open('scoreboard.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([user, f"{points}pts"])
```

**scoreboard.csv**
example: user="john", points=10

```
john,10pts
```

Answer (score 0):

With a csv as:

```
david,12
bill,8
joe,18
henry,15
nathan,10
```

You can use this function:

```py
import csv

def top_five():
    top = []
    all_scores = []

    with open('scores.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        scores = csv.reader(csvfile)

        for row in scores:
            all_scores.append((row[0], int(row[1])))

        top = sorted(
            all_scores, 
            key=lambda score: score[1], 
            reverse=True)
    return top[:5]

print(top_five())
```

If you keep 'pts' in csv, parse result before instert in all_score list.
If you have column name, skip first line in for loop.

#### Sources

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html